# I have my snipe command done, could it snipe images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanna know if my snipe command can somehow snipe images, when I use the snipe on an image, it just sends the embed without the message.
Here is the basic snipe command:

```
bot.sniped_messages = {}
  
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
  bot.sniped_messages[message.guild.id] = (message.content, message.author, message.channel.name, message.created_at)
    
@bot.command()
async def snipe(ctx):
  try:
    contents, author, channel_name, time = bot.sniped_messages[ctx.guild.id]
        
  except:
    await ctx.channel.send("Nemohu najít zprávu na snipenutí.")
    return
  embed = discord.Embed(description=contents,
                        color=ctx.author.color,
                        timestamp=time)
  embed.set_author(name=f"{author.name}#{author.discriminator}", icon_url=author.avatar_url)
  embed.set_footer(text=f"Smazáno v #{channel_name}")
    
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Best would be if you would send me the code :P
Thanks!

A snipe command is a command that gets the last deleted message

Comment: Please specify what you expect this ```snipe``` command to do?

Comment: Right now, it snipes messages greatly, works as intended, but it doesn't snipe images, and I want it to snipe images and messages.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) you need to call message.attachments that will return a list of type [Attachment](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment). However, getting the URL will not work as it would return an error 404.

You will have to save the URL on an on_message and save it to a variable with the message id. Then check if that message id when deleted exists there if so return the URL or s et the image URL that. Discord doesn't delete images from their databases.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```py
@bot.command()
async def check(ctx):
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=100): # gets the last 100 messages
        if message.attachments == []: # checks if there are any attachments
            pass # if there are no attachments it will just move on to the next one
        else: # simple else statement
            if message.author.id == 805485087181242388: # checks if the bot sent the picture, if it did it will not send it (replace 805485087181242388 with your bots id)
                return # does nothing if the bot sended it
            else: # another simple else statement
                await ctx.send(message.attachments[0].url) # gets the last attachment sent, and only sends the url
                return # breaks the command so that the bot will not keep on looking for attachments
```